# Python Excel Dynamic dictionary with dynamic keys (and key values added back in)

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, dynamic

I searched this for a while since started learning Python but can't find it anywhere (likely because I don't fully understand the data structure).

Anyway, I'm trying to create a dynamic dictionary that I intend to then create a table from. Both the rows and columns of this table are dynamic (i.e if new houses or features are added then it would automatically create to suit). The values of each feature is added back in to show the total per house [please see example provided here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGEtK.png). The code I've written is below

```
import os
import openpyxl
import pprint

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\x\\Desktop\\Python test')
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('x.xlsx')
wb.create_sheet('New Sheet')
wb.save('x.xlsx')
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('x +.xlsx')
smry = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Summary')
sheet1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('New Sheet')
smrymaxrow = smry.max_row
smrymaxcol = smry.max_column
House_data = {}
for row in range(2,smrymaxrow):
House = smry['D' + str(row)].value
Feature_name = smry['A' + str(row)].value
Feature_qty = smry['F' + str(row)].value
House_data.setdefault(House, {'Feature' : 'None'})
House not in House_data
House_data[House]={Feature:Feature_qty}
House in House_data
House_data[House][Feature] += Feature_qty

print(House_data.items())
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I'm trying to create a dynamic dictionary called house1, house2, and each dictionary has n features (dynamic keys) and their values added back in to show total.

Comment: [Edit] your Question and add Data from `example provided here. ` as Text.